# How to automatically add recycleApp provider in the *.deploy.cmd file generated by Visual Studio

Tags: msdeploy

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio 2010 to add the recycleApp provider and its value in the deploy.cmd file it generates when building a web deploy package?

W3wp is locking a file in the bin folder and I hope doing an app recycle will make the process release it so the deployment package can be installed.

msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:recycleApp="Default Web Site/myapp" -dest:auto

About the provider: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee522997%28v=ws.10%29.aspx